# rename() returns -1. How to know why rename fails?

Tags: c++, rename, file-rename

I am using c++ stdio.h's

```
int rename ( const char * oldname, const char * newname );
```

rename() function to rename a folder but occasionally it fails to rename the folder and returns -1.

Is there any way to know why is rename() failing?
any way to know this error explanation via any c++ function.

Comment: Check the `errno` variable. Use e.g. [`strerror`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zc53h9bh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to get a printable string.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It should be possible to get the concrete error from errno.h

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
...
if(rename("old","new") == -1)
{
    std::cout << "Error: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
}
```

The `errno` error codes for `rename` are OS-specific:

- [Linux error codes](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rename)
- [Windows error codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/zw5t957f(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) (use `_errno` instead of `errno`)

Comment: Ah, you got it, that the comes from a Windows user and `_errno` is necessary.

Answer (score 3):

C API functions like this typically set `errno` when they fail to give more information. The documentation will usually tell you about `errno` values it might set, and there's also a function called `strerror()` which will take an `errno` value and give you back a `char *` with a human-readable error message in it.

You may need to include `<errno.h>` to access that.

With regard to `rename()` in MFC, this would seem to be the documentation for it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zw5t957f(v=vs.100).aspx which says it sets `errno` to `EACCES`, `ENOENT` or `EINVAL` under various conditions, so check against those to figure out what's going on, with reference to the documentation for the specifics.

Answer (score 2):

*Edit: Since the other questions of the asker if from Windows background I put the focus on the Windows programming environment. Other OS may differ. e.g. GCC/Linux provides `errno` instead of `_errno`*

Check the value of `_errno`. It can be one of these:

```
EACCES: File or directory specified by newname already exists or could not be created (invalid path); or oldname is a directory and newname specifies a different path.
ENOENT: File or path specified by oldname not found.
EINVAL: Name contains invalid characters.
```

Comment: There are many more possible errors which may occur. Here the list for Linux: https://linux.die.net/man/3/rename .. as well note that the underscore is some microsoft specific stuff .. in standard c++ its just 'errno'.

Comment: There are several platform specific questions of the use for Windows (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330121/how-to-save-byte-in-c-sharp-application-settings). Others questions are for Outlook. So I gave the appropriate answer. Why should I bother with Linux stuff?

Comment: Well, just because others did it wrong, does not mean you as well have to do it wrong. Note that C# is mostly used at Windows, where C++ is more multi-plattform. The reporter did not specify a OS .. how it comes that you assume Windows is used ?  Keep in mind that some applications need to run on multiple multiple OS.

Comment: You wouldn't ask if you've followed the link i provided. You find the bang words there that I gave. This would answer your question about the OS background. BTW: The accepted answer also tells you that you are wrong about not using `_errno`.. Also check shf301's answer.

Comment: I followed your link. Well, seems like you realy dont get it. I never said that _errno is generally  wrong. Your post is only about Windows ? Then how about you prefix it with "On Windows:" ?  Than it would be not missleading. Currently others might get the impression that your post is for all OS, but it is not. By the way, the accepted answer is from me. And please check the comment on shf301's answer.

Answer (score 1):

[rename](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zw5t957f%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) will set the [_errno](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3ayayh1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) global variable with the last error number, check that.

Comment: Note that the underscore is some weird Microsoftism. In standard C++, it's called `errno`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Linux you can simply display string representation of error just after fatal call to rename while in gdb:

```
211             if (rename(f_z_name, y) == -1) {
(gdb) n
212                 err = RM_ERR_RENAME_TMP_Y;
(gdb) p errno
$6 = 18
(gdb) p strerr(errno)
No symbol "strerr" in current context.
(gdb) p strerror(errno)
$7 = 0x7ffff7977aa2 "Invalid cross-device link"
(gdb)
```

Answer (score -2):

if the file is open, please close it before change the name. The code below won't work and the file name can't be changed.

```
ofstream _file("C:\\yourfile.txt", ofstream::app); 

if (-1 == rename("C:\\yourfile.txt", "C:\\yourfile2.txt"))
     puts("The file doesn't exist or already deleted");

_file.close();
```

Comment: Why answer a 2 year old question, who already has an accepted answer and your answer is completely irrelevant to original problem.