# How to save byte[] in c# application settings

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, listview, application-settings

I am trying to save a byte array (byte[]) in c# application settings that is returned by [Object List View](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html).

Can anyone give me a solution on how to save byte array in c# application settings?
or some trick on how to convert byte[] to something like a string then store, then retrieve and again convert it to byte array and give it back to object list view.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

One of the most common ways to make a string from an array of bytes is encoding them in [Base-64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64):

```
string encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(toEncodeAsBytes);
```

Use

```
byte[] bytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(encoded);
```

to get your bytes back.

Comment: My top favorite :)

Answer (score 4):

The canonical way to do this is to convert the `byte[]` to a `string` via base64 and the other way round.

Answer (score 3):

By Different way you can convert Byte array to string and string to byte array. Like this :

1)

```
string asciiString = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(byteArray);

byte[] byte = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(asciiString);
```

2)

```
string base64String = System.Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray);

byte[] byte = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
```

3)

```
string utf8String = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray);

byte[] byte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(utf8String);
```

you can also use System.Text.Encoding.BigEndianUnicode, System.Text.Encoding.Unicode, and System.Text.Encoding.UTF32 for converting Byte Array  to string and string to Byte Array.

Hope, It should help you.