# Rename file on Windows 8 in C++

Tags: c++, windows-8.1

I am working on a Windows 8 machine running a C++ project.  I sometimes receive a -1 response for the following line of code.  Is there another way to rename a file that will work?

```
    std::rename(oldFileName, newFileName);
```

Comment: rename should work. Check errno (strerror...) why it fails.

Comment: Reasons `rename` can fail: the file does not exist; the file is open; the file would need to be copied (like to another disk); the new name already exists.

Comment: The error code is -1.  The method works perfectly fine on Windows 7 machines.

Comment: The specific return value means nothing! What does `perror("")` say?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299495/rename-returns-1-how-to-know-why-rename-fails

Comment: Possibly UAC is responsible. You can use the SysInternals Process Monitor tool to monitor your process and see the exact error code returned from the operating system to your process.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I was able to solve the problem, it was due to Windows 8 restrictions in the C drive. (See answer below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to receive output from perror but I was able to figure out the solution.

Last week there was a Windows updated (unknown to me because it was not my computer) that put more restrictions on the C drive. My oldFileName was located in the C drive and because of those restrictions, it would not rename the file.  **I had to move the file location out of the C drive.**